# How do I get the exact same text font in the rest of the HTML page

Tags: html, css

```css
.home {
      background: url(download.png);
      background-size: 1500px;
      overflow: ;
      background-position: -130px -20px;
    }
    
    .content h2 {
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
      font-size: 45px;
      font-weight: 900;
      line-height: 50px;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 50px;
      z-index: 200;
    }
    
    .content h2::before {
      content: "";
      background: linear-gradient(130deg, #1951bf 0%, #25b7c7 89%);
      position: absolute;
      height: 14px;
      width: 334px;
      filter: opacity(0.4);
      top: 77px;
      z-index: -200;
    }
    
    .content p {
      width: ;
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #3a505f;
      letter-spacing: 1.1px;
      line-height: 26px;
      z-index: 200;
      transform: scale(1.04, 1.1);
    }
    
    .home {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: ;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      color: black;
      z-index: -100;
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
   family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <div class="home">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>No-Code<br>Payment Platform</h2>
      <p>PayRequest makes it easy to create your own branded payment page, and to send payment links to all your customers.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Above is the code for the site I am building.

**The UI of the page I want to rectify:** [click-here-to-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogNWD.png)

**The original UI:** [click-here-to-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQz2C.png)

I have the exact same font-family down and I have tried different sizes and weights but I am not able to get the exact same text as the original site in the p section. I have got the same one down in h2 but not in p.

Can somebody help to resolve this issue, please?

Comment: can you provide the HTML and CSS code of that section, please?

Comment: please check out the edited version

Comment: Parts of your body are missing. In the first photo you provided, there are few more paras at the bottom. They are the texts which are not working like the texts in the top section. Please make sure to provide a clear question. You have only provided two photos and asked why the difference. Now you provided a partial code. This type of behavior can lead to downvotes from the other members in the community.

Comment: Check the edit I have added. When you post a question/answer in the community always follow that procedure. Please follow the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In h2 you have font-family: 'Source Sans Pro' but in p you have 'Poppins'. So this is why they are two different fonts. You can either declare a universal font family using *{} or you can just switch the font family in p to 'Source Sans Pro'

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same font-family for the elements in your css. h2 and p and different font-family. Also if you put everything in the a < body> tag you can just define the font-family in their rather than adding it in every element like so:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```